# How to Split Audio using Sox Depending on Input Variables

Tags: bash, shell

I want to split a stereo audio into two mono files. To run my program I am passing three arguments. `./program.sh /folder_path KHZ_TYPE C12_or_L2R` and depending on the variables I want to split the audio file into two mono files and name them either `output_ch1.wav and output_ch2.wav` or `output_left.wav and output_right.wav`. Below is my code.

But I keep getting `` syntax error near unexpected token `then' ``.
Also How do I save the result files into a directory called `output_files`?

```
DIR=$1
KHZ=$2
TYPE=$3
CMD_1=""
CMD_2=""

for filename in $DIR/*; do
    filename="${filename##*/}"
    echo $filename
    fname="${filename// /_}"
    fname="${fname%.*}"

    if[$KHZ = "8KHZ"] && [$TYPE = "L2R"]; then
        output_left = "${fname}_left.wav"
        output_right = "${fname}_right.wav"
        $CMD_1 = "sox -r 8000 -b 16 $filename $output_left remix 1"
        $CMD_2 = "sox -r 8000 -b 16 $filename $output_right remix 2"
    elif[$KHZ = "8KHZ"] && [$TYPE = "C12"]; then
        output_ch1 = "${fname}_ch1.wav"
        output_ch2 = "${fname}_ch2.wav"
        $CMD_1 = "sox -r 8000 -b 16 $filename $output_ch1 remix 1"
        $CMD_2 = "sox -r 8000 -b 16 $filename $output_ch2 remix 2"
    elif[$KHZ = "16KHZ"] && [$TYPE = "C12"]; then
        output_ch1 = "${fname}_ch1.wav"
        output_ch2 = "${fname}_ch2.wav"
        $CMD_1 = "sox -r 16000 -b 16 $filename $output_ch1 remix 1"
        $CMD_2 = "sox -r 16000 -b 16 $filename $output_ch2 remix 2"
    elif[$KHZ = "16KHZ"] && [$TYPE = "L2R"]; then
        output_left = "${fname}_left.wav"
        output_right = "${fname}_right.wav"
        $CMD_1 = "sox -r 16000 -b 16 $filename $output_left remix 1"
        $CMD_2 = "sox -r 16000 -b 16 $filename $output_right remix 2"
done
```

Comment: You need a `fi` just before the final `done`.

Comment: Also, remove all whitespace around `=` signs.

Comment: And I advise you to put all occurrences of `$TYPE` in double quotes.

Comment: And also `$DIR` and other referenced variables in double quotes.

Comment: Place a space after each `if` or `elif` (before the opening brackets `[`).

Comment: Also place spaces before each closing bracket `]`.

Comment: Then remove all `$~ signs on the Left Hand Side of all assignments (this isn't PHP after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but do inspect the differences, esp. those in whitespace, double quoting, and `$` removed in LHS variables.

Here's a simpler version. Please double check that I'm doing the correct thing as far as the rates go:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"
KHZ="$2"
TYPE="$3"
CMD_1=""
CMD_2=""

for filename in "$DIR"/*; do
    filename="${filename##*/}"
    echo "filename=$filename"
    fname="${filename// /_}"
    fname="${fname%.*}"
    echo "fname=$fname"

    output_left="${fname}_left.wav"
    output_right="${fname}_right.wav"

    if [ "$KHZ" = "8KHZ" ] && [ "$TYPE" = "L2R" ]; then
        rate="8000"
    elif [ "$KHZ" = "8KHZ" ] && [ "$TYPE" = "C12" ]; then
        rate=8000
    elif [ "$KHZ" = "16KHZ" ] && [ "$TYPE" = "C12" ]; then
        rate=16000
    elif [ "$KHZ" = "16KHZ" ] && [ "$TYPE" = "L2R" ]; then
        rate=16000
    fi

    echo "rate=$rate"
    CMD_1="sox -r $rate -b 16 $filename $output_left remix 1"
    CMD_2="sox -r $rate -b 16 $filename $output_right remix 2"

    # using parenthesis means: run in subshell
    # when subshell exits, we're back in the original 
    # directory, i.e. no need to cd back to it :-)
    (
        cd "$DIR"
        $CMD_1
        $CMD_2
    )

done
```

Comment: I keep getting ```sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `Test2.wav': No such file or directory``` when I run ```./program.sh audios 8KHZ L2R```

Comment: I haven't run the script here, but I advise you to echo "$filename" and see what that amounts to; note: I just edited the script!

Comment: ```Test1.wav
Test2.wav
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `Test2.wav': No such file or directory
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `Test2.wav': No such file or directory``` why does it only complains about test2.wav?

Comment: I found out that ```filename="${filename##*/}"``` was causing the problem that it couldn't find the correct path. However, that means the program is skipping ```Test1.wav```

Comment: You do want to cd to "$DIR", correct?  I made some more edits to the second version.

Comment: Well not really, my file structure is simple. In a folder there is ```program.sh``` and ```audios``` folder that contains wav files. And I simply want to run my program for all of them. But it keep skipping Test1.wav

Comment: Some more edits. I tested it here and it should work. Note esp. that earlier I forgot the underscores in `$CMD1` and `$CMD2.`.

Comment: The reason was that the commands should be run before done. That did the trick. Thank you! I have last one question. How do I put the output files in a different directory?

Comment: To output in a different directory, you could add it as a static variable or as a command-line option. Let's say you have "ODIR=/foo/bar" near the top. Then you could build CMD_1 with `$ODIR/$output_left`, etc.

Comment: Was that clear? Or do you want me to make an edit so you can see what I mean?